# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'logdir'

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, pytorch

I'm new for NLP.I encounter the issue,as follows:
'''TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'logdir''''
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Add the `error stack trace` and `code` which is generating the error to the description.

Answer (score 0):

We could have done detailed investigation if you had provided some code.
Anyways, for `Tensorboard`, hyper-parameter `logdir` and `log_dir` are used at different situation.
Refer the below links for detailed understanding and use it accordingly.

1. [logdir](https://tensorboardx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tensorboard.html#tensorboardX.SummaryWriter.__init)
2. [log_dir](https://tensorboardx.readthedocs.io/en/v1.6/tensorboard.html#tensorboardX.SummaryWriter.__init)